# Find radius of convergence without finding series

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find the radius of convergence for the Taylor series of these functions
$$
f(z) = \frac{\sqrt{z+2i}}{z-3i}, \quad a=-1
$$
and
$$
g(z) = \int_0^z \frac{(t-\sin{t})}{t^2+4}dt, \quad a = 2
$$
As I understand both of these functions are analytic at their respective points $a$, so to find the radius of convergence it suffices to look at the distance to the nearest singularity. For $f(z)$ there are singularities at $z=0$ and $z = 3i$ and hence the radius is $1$.

For $g(z)$ I believe that integrating power series does not change the radius so we can look at the function under the integral sign, which has singularities at $\pm 2i$ and so the radius is $2$. Is this correct or am I going wrong somewhere?

**EDIT:**

For $f(z)$ I meant that it has a singularity when $z+2i=0$ so at $z=-2i$ which means the radius should be $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Why should $f$ have a singularity at $0$?

Comment: Ah I meant when $z+2i=0$ so at $-2i$

Comment: Yes, that's right. And of course the radius of convergence then is not $1$.

Comment: You are going about it correctly. A subtlety not seen in these examples is that $f$ may be continuous on the $closure$ of the circle of convergence but $f'$ (or maybe only $f''$, or ...) may have a singularity on the boundary.

Comment: For the second problem, you found the correct singularities, but your radius of convergence is wrong. Remember that you are expanding about $z = 2$, not $z = 0$.